# query the data day by day

Tags: php, mysql

i have this database table name clicks

```
id  userid  siteID  date
1   3       1       2014-02-15
2   3       2       2014-02-15
3   3       3       2014-02-15
4   3       4       2014-02-15
5   3       5       2014-02-15
6   3       4       2014-02-16
7   3       5       2014-02-16
8   3       6       2014-02-16
9   3       7       2014-02-16
10  3       8       2014-02-16
11  3       9       2014-02-17
12  3       5       2014-02-17
13  3       4       2014-02-17
14  3       1       2014-02-17
15  3       1       2014-02-17
16  3       2       2014-02-18
18  3       3       2014-02-18
18  3       4       2014-02-18
19  3       7       2014-02-18
20  3       6       2014-02-18
21  3       1       2014-02-19
22  3       2       2014-02-19
23  3       3       2014-02-19
24  3       4       2014-02-19
25  3       5       2014-02-19
26  3       8       2014-02-19
```

my quesion is how to count clicks by every day by userID

i want output like

```
userid   clicks  date
3        5       2014-02-15
3        5       2014-02-16
3        5       2014-02-17
3        5       2014-02-18
3        5       2014-02-19
```

hope my question is clear

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ? Can you post your so far efforts ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT userid ,COUNT(id) as clicks,`date`FROM `table` GROUP BY `date`,userid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with [**count()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/counting-rows.html)

```
SELECT userid ,
COUNT(userid) clicks,
`date`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `date`,userid
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple [Group By](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause will do:

```
SELECT userid, count(id) as clicks, date
FROM table
GROUP BY userid, date
ORDER BY date, userid
```

Don't forget to include the `userid` in the grouping.